using driver or expression to link to other node in compositor
I'm trying to create an expression to get data from other nodes ( or from the input pipe of a current node). Let say in the compositor I have 2 nodes : image node (labeled as laptop) and a scale node. In the scale node, I want to add expression/driver to the X scale to get the value of its input width ( In this case the width resolution of the Image from 'laptop' node ). Something like : laptop.width() or input.width()

How can I do this ?
